# How to do singleton serialization in C#?

Tags: c#

I go to the MSDN to search the **singleton serialization**, and find the source code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.aspx
but I had problems when I changed some part of the code. I divide it into two program : serialization and deserialization. Below is the Main function of the two(other classes are in the msdn documentation, link is at the second line).
Serialization program is below:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

    try 
    {
        // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it 
        // to serialize the data to the stream.
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Create an array with multiple elements refering to 
        // the one Singleton object.
        Singleton[] a1 = { Singleton.GetSingleton(), Singleton.GetSingleton() };

        a1[0].SomeNumber = 555;

        formatter.Serialize(fs, a1);

    }   
    catch (SerializationException e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
    }
```

Deserialization program:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);

    try 
    {
        // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it 
        // to serialize the data to the stream.
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();


        Singleton[] a2 = (Singleton[]) formatter.Deserialize(fs);

        // This displays "True".
        Console.WriteLine(a2[0].SomeNumber);
    }   
    catch (SerializationException e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
    }
```

After I executed the two program, the console didn't print 555 but still 123, why? I can't figure it out and got stuck in it for the whole day, can anybody help me ?

Comment: What is `Singleton`? Where does 123 come from?

Comment: Why do you want to serialize a singleton???

Comment: How can you assign 555 to `SomeNumber` and expect `Console.WriteLine(a2[0].SomeNumber);` to display 'True'? What is your `Singleton` then?

Comment: Would you be willing to elaborate on your use case for wanting to do this?  Anyone else really curious about: Singleton[] a1 = { Singleton.GetSingleton(), Singleton.GetSingleton() };? :-)

Comment: @lgor Korkhov  I just give the two Main() function in the two program, other parts is in the link, it's the msdn source code, could you help me find where i got it wrong? why still the default number 123?

Comment: @ValAkkapeddi This is the msdn source code, you can click the link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.aspx]

Comment: @Oded  I'm a beginner of C# programming. And I'm designing a downloader. I think the developing process should contain the library developing and app developing, and my library contains a TaskManager class, I think it should be a singleton class in case that the app developer(in this program i act as both library developer and app developer, but i just try to separate the roles) create several instances of the class and result in app crash. Do you think it's worth using the Singleton?

Comment: No, this is not a valid reason for using a singleton. This is a simply pattern and gets abused because it is so simple. The rule is - if the application must (really, really, must) have only one instance (and needs to enforce this rule) then use a singleton. If in doubt, do not use a singleton.

Comment: @Oded But I think in an app there shouldn't be two TaskManager class in it, this is not a situation to use singleton?

Comment: Is that an actual requirement? Is it an error to have more than one instance of the class? Would having more than one instance cause problems?

Comment: It will cause problems, can a downloader have two different task manager? If so task management will do whose order? And different manager have different task lists, isn't it a chaos?

Answer (score 5):

I believe you will find many answers on this documentation : [IObjectReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.runtime.serialization.iobjectreference%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Serializing `Singletons` never is really easy. But do you really have to serialize them, and then deserialize them ?

Here is a code sample from the MSDN link I provided :

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security.Permissions;


// There should be only one instance of this type per AppDomain.
[Serializable]
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
[AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, 
    Level=AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
public sealed class Singleton : ISerializable 
{
    // This is the one instance of this type.
    private static readonly Singleton theOneObject = new Singleton();

    // Here are the instance fields.
    private string someString_value;
    private Int32 someNumber_value;

   public string SomeString
   {
       get{return someString_value;}
       set{someString_value = value;}
   }

   public Int32 SomeNumber
   {
       get{return someNumber_value;}
       set{someNumber_value = value;}
   }

    // Private constructor allowing this type to construct the Singleton.
    private Singleton() 
    { 
        // Do whatever is necessary to initialize the Singleton.
        someString_value = "This is a string field";
        someNumber_value = 123;
    }

    // A method returning a reference to the Singleton.
    public static Singleton GetSingleton() 
    { 
        return theOneObject; 
    }

    // A method called when serializing a Singleton.
   [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, 
   Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(
        SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
    {
        // Instead of serializing this object, 
        // serialize a SingletonSerializationHelp instead.
        info.SetType(typeof(SingletonSerializationHelper));
        // No other values need to be added.
    }

    // Note: ISerializable's special constructor is not necessary 
    // because it is never called.
}


[Serializable]
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, 
    Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
[AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, 
   Level=AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
internal sealed class SingletonSerializationHelper : IObjectReference 
{
    // This object has no fields (although it could).

    // GetRealObject is called after this object is deserialized.
    public Object GetRealObject(StreamingContext context) 
    {
        // When deserialiing this object, return a reference to 
        // the Singleton object instead.
        return Singleton.GetSingleton();
    }
}


class App 
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

        try 
        {    
            // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it 
            // to serialize the data to the stream.
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            // Create an array with multiple elements refering to 
            // the one Singleton object.
            Singleton[] a1 = { Singleton.GetSingleton(), Singleton.GetSingleton() };

            // This displays "True".
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Do both array elements refer to the same object? " + 
                (a1[0] == a1[1]));     

            // Serialize the array elements.
            formatter.Serialize(fs, a1);

            // Deserialize the array elements.
            fs.Position = 0;
            Singleton[] a2 = (Singleton[]) formatter.Deserialize(fs);

            // This displays "True".
            Console.WriteLine("Do both array elements refer to the same object? " 
                + (a2[0] == a2[1])); 

            // This displays "True".
            Console.WriteLine("Do all array elements refer to the same object? " 
                + (a1[0] == a2[0]));
        }   
        catch (SerializationException e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally 
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a beginner of C# programming. And I'm designing a downloader. I think the developing process should contain the library developing and app developing, and my library contains a TaskManager class, I think it should be a singleton class in case that the app developer(in this program i act as both library developer and app developer, but i just try to separate the roles) create several instances of the class and result in app crash. Do you think it's worth using the Singleton?

Comment: And your reference is just what i got in msdn, I just change the Main() function of its source code and divide the serialization and deserialization into two programs, why don't i get the 555 but still 123?

Comment: I cant tell if you require a Singleton or not, only you can decide if it is necessary or not. I believe the Singleton is widely overused, and in some cases, can lead to problems. In your case for example, having a singleton complicates the serialisation. Also, it depends on what kind of singleton you are using. If its fully lazy, deserializing it shouldnt be much of a problem. If it isnt, you will need a meticulus implementation of the IObjectReference interface

Comment: what do you mean for "fully lazy"? can you explain it?

Comment: Lazy instanciation is a type of instanciation, where you wait till the last moment and only instanciate your object when you need it (typically when you call it). You also have other types of instanciation (eager for example).

Comment: Why deserializing a fully lazy singleton is no problem?

Comment: Because you can deserialize without calling the constructor. And because its fully lazy (nothing is existing before the first call) you can "fill" the singleton with its pre serialization state.

Comment: I think i got it, do you mean before it's deserialized, every member of it has been loaded so I can fill the singleton then deserialize it?

Comment: Are you aware that that link goes to the French language documentation instead of the default one?

Answer (score 1):

**Okay, so first, to answer your main question:**

Your implementation for ISerializable.GetObjectData is using IObjectReference.GetRealObject to fetch a reference to an object already existing on your class loader heap.  In other words, no deserialization isn't creating an object and using the setters to populate the serialized data for you - it's just reaching into memory and giving you the instance you modified to '555'.

This works in the sample because everything's happening in the same process - your "deserialization" simply gets a reference to the Singleton instance that you modified earlier.  When you split off the deserialize into another program, it fetches the only 'Singleton' reference it knows - the static instance assigned to theOneObject, which was initialized with '123'.

**So here's how I would do what you want:**

Make your TaskManager a singleton if you want (although a static class seems sufficient), but do not serialize the singleton.  Instead, store your state (all your tasks, etc) in another TaskList object that is a static and immutable field of your TaskManager, that is deserialized inside a static constructor or threadsafe singleton initialization.  Don't expose the TaskList reference directly - let methods on your TaskManager class control access to it - AddTask, DeleteTask, GetTaskStatus, etc.

Your data's unique, but it's taken care of in a somewhat nicer, easier to implement manner.

Comment: Thanks very much for your patient explaination.  In your answer you say "although a static class seems sufficient", what's the different between singleton and static class? I always regard them as the same thing.

Comment: No sir, not really the same. Singleton is a technique to make sure there's only one instance of a class, but a static class never gets instantiated - check out this (.NET Perls article)[http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton-static]. IMHO, a static class has cleaner semantics and a simpler implementation that fit your use-case well. Singletons can do all the things non-static classes can, like implement interfaces, etc - but (YAGNI)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it] IMO. You can always refactor later if you decide otherwise.